# Count & breakdown tweets I received

Tags: api, twitter

Is there any way to count how many people tweeted to me and included a certain hashtag and have a breakdown by user, for instance,

- User A tweeted to me using #certainhashtag 10 times
- User B tweeted to me using #certainhashtag 8 times

*etc*.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the search API (https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html) with the q parameter with `@you #certainhashtag`.

So here you have tweets mentionning you and containing your hashtag.

You can write them to a CSV file. To perform the counts, on a linux system, you will achieve it with a few commands like : awk, cut, grep, wc, uniq...

Or when getting tweets you can code a filter like this  :

- if the sender user of the tweet is @you : pass (results can return tweets from you)
- manage a counter for each user id.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the premium search APIs to do this, using the [counts endpoint](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/premium-search.html#CountsEndpoint). Both the 30-day and full archive search APIs support counts, at the paid premium tier (not available in the free sandbox).

You'd make a query similar to this one, to get back a time series of counts data.

```
{
    "query": "to:andypiper from:userA #certainhashtag",
    "bucket": "day"
}
```

The results look something like this (for a 30-day search request):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "timePeriod": "201809040000",
            "count": 2
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201809030000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201809020000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201809010000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808310000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808300000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808290000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808280000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808270000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808260000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808250000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808240000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808230000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808220000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808210000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808200000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808190000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808180000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808170000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808160000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808150000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808140000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808130000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808120000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808110000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808100000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808090000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808080000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808070000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808060000",
            "count": 0
        },
        {
            "timePeriod": "201808050000",
            "count": 0
        }
    ],
    "totalCount": 2,
    "requestParameters": {
        "bucket": "day",
        "fromDate": "201808050000",
        "toDate": "201809041241"
    }
}
```

Then you simply need to total the counts.